# Is there any mysql query which restores disk space after delete query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wso2

I am trying to clear my database by deleting records from 'ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY' by mysql cleanup script. The problem is after that my database size doesn't change.

I was reading some advices about `optimize table` and configuration `innodb file per table` which doesn't satisfy myself.

Cleanup script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST$$
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_ACT_HI_TASKINST$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cleanInstance$$
CREATE PROCEDURE cleanInstance(limitCount INT, lastActive DATETIME, processName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
        SELECT(' Start deleting activiti instance data with instance ids ');
    START TRANSACTION;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST AS SELECT * FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST WHERE PROC_DEF_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM ACT_RE_PROCDEF  WHERE NAME_ = processName) AND END_TIME_ is not NULL AND END_TIME_ < lastActive order by ID_ asc LIMIT limitCount OFFSET 0; 
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_ACT_HI_TASKINST AS ( SELECT ACT_HI_TASKINST.ID_ FROM ACT_HI_TASKINST INNER JOIN  TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST ON 
        ACT_HI_TASKINST.PROC_INST_ID_ = TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST.PROC_INST_ID_);

        DELETE byteArray FROM ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY byteArray WHERE ID_ IN (SELECT BYTEARRAY_ID_ FROM ACT_HI_VARINST WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST WHERE ID_ is not null));

        DELETE actinst FROM ACT_HI_ACTINST actinst INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST tempProcinst ON actinst.PROC_INST_ID_ = tempProcinst.PROC_INST_ID_ WHERE actinst.PROC_INST_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE historyComment FROM ACT_HI_COMMENT historyComment INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_TASKINST taskInst ON historyComment.TASK_ID_ = taskInst.ID_ WHERE historyComment.TASK_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE historyComment FROM ACT_HI_COMMENT historyComment INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST tempProcinst ON historyComment.PROC_INST_ID_ = tempProcinst.PROC_INST_ID_  WHERE historyComment.PROC_INST_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE identityLink FROM ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK identityLink INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_TASKINST  tempTaskinst ON identityLink.TASK_ID_ = tempTaskinst.ID_ WHERE identityLink.TASK_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE identityLink FROM ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK identityLink INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST tempProcinst ON identityLink.PROC_INST_ID_ = tempProcinst.PROC_INST_ID_ WHERE  
               identityLink.PROC_INST_ID_ is not null;

        DELETE varinst FROM ACT_HI_VARINST varinst INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_TASKINST taskInst ON varinst.TASK_ID_ = taskInst.ID_ WHERE varinst.TASK_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE varinst FROM ACT_HI_VARINST varinst INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST tempProcinst ON varinst.PROC_INST_ID_ = tempProcinst.PROC_INST_ID_ WHERE varinst.PROC_INST_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE attachment FROM ACT_HI_ATTACHMENT attachment INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_TASKINST taskInst ON attachment.TASK_ID_ = taskInst.ID_ WHERE attachment.TASK_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE attachment FROM ACT_HI_ATTACHMENT attachment INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST taskInst ON attachment.PROC_INST_ID_ = taskInst.PROC_INST_ID_ WHERE attachment.PROC_INST_ID_ is not null;
        DELETE taskInst FROM ACT_HI_TASKINST taskInst INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_TASKINST tempTaskInst ON taskInst.ID_ = tempTaskInst.ID_ WHERE taskInst.ID_ is not null;
        DELETE procInst FROM ACT_HI_PROCINST procInst INNER JOIN TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST tempProcInst ON procInst.PROC_INST_ID_ = tempProcInst.PROC_INST_ID_ WHERE procInst.PROC_INST_ID_ is not null;

        COMMIT;
        SELECT(' End deleting activiti instance data with instance ids ');
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SET @LIMIT_COUNT =2147483647;
SET @PROCESS_NAME = 'FinalizeRegister';
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 0 DAY) INTO @LAST_ACTIVE; 
SELECT(' Starting cleanInstance procedure ');
CALL cleanInstance(@LIMIT_COUNT, @LAST_ACTIVE, @PROCESS_NAME);
SELECT (' Ending cleanInstance procedure ');
```

`DELETE byteArray FROM ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY byteArray WHERE ID_ IN (SELECT BYTEARRAY_ID_ FROM ACT_HI_VARINST WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ IN (SELECT ID_ FROM TEMP_ACT_HI_PROCINST WHERE ID_ is not null));`

Is there any query which shrinks database size after this delete query? Like in oracle databases `SHRINK SPACE`

Comment: What do you mean by "some advices about optimize table and configuration innodb file per table which doesn't satisfy myself."? Didn't you like it and are looking for a different way, or didn't you understand it/didn't it work for you? Cause that's basically what you need to do.

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to shrink that database as we can do in oracle db by adding ```SHRINK SPACE``` at the end of the query. I wanted to run the script and avoid configurating of mysql.

Comment: innodb file per table is enabled by default since 2010, so check your configuration, you might not have to change it. alter/optimize/drop+create a table is the only way to shrink it in mysql though (assuming you use file per table, otherwise you cannot).